# How to find inflection point of sigmoid curve?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I can't seem to take the derivative of a sigmoid learning curve function consistently. I've tried a few times with different results. Also, at the end I don't even see how to find the roots! The easiest way I've found so far for the derivative is to use the power and chain rule instead of the quotient rule.

Starting with:

$$\frac{100}{(1+30e^{-0.3t})}$$

I move the denominator to the top and take the first derivative:

$$(-1)\cdot(1+30e^{-0.3t})^{-2}\cdot(-9e^{-0.3t})$$

For the second derivative I'll need to use the product rule:

$$(2)\cdot(1+30e^{-0.3t})^{-3}\cdot(-9e^{-0.3t})+(-1)(1+30e^{-0.3t})^{-2}\cdot(2.7e^{-0.3t})$$

To simplify my thought was to put the terms in fraction form and find a common denominator:

$$\frac{(-18e^{-0.3t})-(2.7e^{-0.3t})\cdot(1+30e^{-0.3t})}{(1+30e^{-0.3t})^{3}}$$

I don't see a place where the denominator would be undefined, so to the find the roots I should just set the numerator equal to zero and solve for t, right?

$$-20.7e^{-0.3t}-81e^{-0.6t^2}=0$$

How do I solve for t here so I can find the inflection point? Did I do the derivative right? This is a homework question, but the answer is already given to me as 11.3373. I just don't know how to get there!

Comment: Your term $e^{-0.6 t^2}$ is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It sure looks ugly... but use the chain rule instead of fooling around. Call $e^{-0.3 t} = x$, so that:

$\begin{align*}
  \frac{d \sigma}{d t}
    &= \frac{d \sigma}{d x} \cdot \frac{d x}{d t} \\
  \frac{d^2 \sigma}{d t^2}
    &= \frac{d^2 \sigma}{d x^2} \cdot \frac{d x}{d t}
         + \frac{d \sigma}{d x} \cdot \frac{d^2 x}{d t^2} \\
  \frac{d x}{d t}
    &= -0.3 x \\
  \frac{d^2 x}{d t^2}
    &= 0.09 x \\
  \sigma(x)
    &= \frac{100}{1 + 30 x} \\
  \frac{d \sigma}{d x}
    &= - \frac{3000}{1 + 30 x)^2} \\
  \frac{d^2 \sigma}{d x^2}
    &= \frac{1800}{(1 + 30 x)^3}
\end{align*}$

This gives a somewhat easier to work with equation for the inflection point in terms of $x$. We know $x \ne 0$:

$\begin{align*}
   0
     &= - \frac{3000}{1 + 30 x)^2} \cdot (-0.3 x)
           + \frac{1800}{(1 + 30 x)^3} \cdot (0.09 x) \\
     &= 900 (1 + 30 x) + 162 \\
     &= 2700 x + 1062
\end{align*}$

But this gives a negative $x$, which is impossible. No inflection point. But this much was obvious (in hindsight): The function $\sigma(t)$ is strictly increasing. Perhaps a sign error in $\sigma$?

Answer (score 0):

$$f(t)=\frac{100}{(1+30e^{-0.3t})}$$
$$f'(t)=\frac{900 e^{-0.3 t}}{\left(1+30 e^{-0.3 t}\right)^2}$$
$$f''(t)=\frac{16200 e^{-0.6 t}}{\left(1+30 e^{-0.3 t}\right)^3}-\frac{270 e^{-0.3
   t}}{\left(1+30 e^{-0.3 t}\right)^2}$$ So, if $f''(t)=0$
$$16200 e^{-0.6 t}=270 e^{-0.3t}\left(1+30 e^{-0.3 t}\right)=270 e^{-0.3t}+8100e^{-0.6 t}$$
$$16200=270 e^{0.3t}+8100 \implies 8100=270e^{0.3t}\implies e^{0.3t}=30\implies 0.3t=\log(30)\implies t=\frac{\log(30)}{0.3}\approx 11.3373$$